# Function Now() in Access VBA 64 bit

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

My company just updated MS Office to the latest 365 version and now I have an issue in Access VBA.
The following query is not working any longer

```
SELECT Tbl_Customers.Name, Tbl_Customers.*, * FROM Tbl_Customers WHERE (((Tbl_Customers.CustomerType)=1) AND ((Tbl_Customers.NextAppointment)>Now()));
```

It throws me a compiler error because it seems the function Now() is not recognised any longer.

I have googled it but I cannot find any useful information about that.

Answer (score 2):

I have just found out that a few `Declare PtrSafe Function...` were missing. The query is working again now.